# MIME type with jQuery 2.0.0

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer, mime

I have the following code to solve the IE local access XML issue:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: options.xmlUrl,
        dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
        success: function(data) {wrapTree(data);},
        error:function(){alert(options.loadingError);}
    });
```

It is not working with jQuery 2.0.0 due to $.browser. The recommendation at http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests is no longer valid. Anyone know how should it be adapted to run with the jQuery current version?

Comment: Check out Modernizr - it might have a test for what you need to figure out, it's always my first stop

Comment: it's worth pointing out that the documentation at docs.jquery.com is obsolete (as stated here: http://docs.jquery.com/) and being replaced with api.jquery.com, so don't rely on it as a good source. (especially the article you linked, which does seem like it's probably quite old, since it's using an activeX object in the success code -- yikes!)

Comment: jqueryrocks, Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Spudley, Thank you. I have not seen the statement.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `dataType: "text"` for all cases and then `data = $.parseXML(data)` in the success handler to turn it into XML on all browsers.

Comment: Hello Dave. Can you tell me how to change the complete code? $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: options.xmlUrl, dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml", success: function(data) {wrapTree(data);}, error:function(){alert(options.loadingError);} }); function wrapTree(data){ var xml; if (typeof data == "string") { xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"); xml.async = false; xml.loadXML(data); } else { xml = data; }

Comment: Something like this:
```
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {wrapTree($.parseXML(data));},
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$.browser` feature has been removed from jQuery since v1.9, and it was deprecated and not recommended for use as long ago as v1.3. They recommend feature detection instead for most use cases rather than browser detection.

Given how long ago the `$.browser` feature was deprecated, if a jQuery page is recommending using it, then that page is likely very old as well -- in fact, it's quite likely that newer versions of jQuery don't need this hack at all. Have you tried just leaving it out entirely?

If you *really* need it, you can use the [jQuery migrate library](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme), which puts back all the depreated features that were removed from v1.9 onward, including `$.browser`.

However, if at all possible, I would suggest trying to find a solution that doesn't involve this feature, as the Migrate library is intended solving for short-term upgrade problems, not as a long-term solution; jQuery may not support it in future versions.

I'd also say that since you're using jQuery 2.0, you should note that this version drops support for IE v6, 7 and 8. If you need to support older IE version, you'll need to stick with jQuery 1.x. More importantly, if you are sticking with v2.0, you're only supporting IE v9 and up. I don't know about this specific issue, but it's possible that it may only be an issue in older IE versions, so you may not even need this hack at all. It would be worth checking.

Hope that helps.